# Commas before titles

Tags: commas

There are probably more descriptive/intelligent ways to title this question.

When you're describing someone by name and title like "Peter, the Dragon", is it valid and tasteful to omit the comma? It seems to me if you're so used to calling him "Peter the Dragon" then "the Dragon" becomes part of his name so having a comma there would create dissonance between the rhythm of the words and the rhythm I want to hear in my mind. But it still feels wrong.

Comment: Most references to "Blackbeard the [P]irate" don't use the comma. It's a style choice, really. The commas make it an aside instead of integral. "William the Conqueror", or "William, the Conqueror"?

Comment: @medica Beautifully concise. I'd not have been able to resist adding _Attila the Hun_,  _Alexander the Great_, _Ethelred the Unready_, _Gandalf the Grey_ and _Asterix the Gaul_. Not to mention _Winnie the Pooh_.

Comment: @medica thanks yall. i just needed everything to work out mathematically in my world. the concept of it being a sort of combination descriptor/name makes sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the commas indicates an alternative expression

> Peter, the dragon, went to school

implies that you could perfectly well have said

> Peter went to school

or

> The dragon went to school

so this form should only be used where we know already that a particular dragon, "the" dragon, not just "a" dragon is referred to.

> Peter the Dragon went to school

is using Peter the Dragon as a title, not as two alternative expressions. This is why Dragon has a capital D here as it is part of the title.

A third option exists

> Peter, a dragon, went to school

which is appropriate where Peter the Dragon is not a title, and we do not already know we are talking of a particular "the" dragon. In this case we are giving additional information about Peter, that he happens to be a dragon.

Peter, the headmaster, went to school

Peter, a teacher, went to school

Peter the Great went to school

Comment: Thank you. The concept of it not needing a comma because it is his full title makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret it in two ways but I see no difference.

1) Peter the Dragon went to school (wow...)

2) Peter, the Dragon, went to school.

In the second sentence I see it as an extra information like in the sentence;

Peter, who is a Dragon, went to school.

So, when you say the first sentence it is obvious, Peter is a dragon. 
In the second sentence, it is a little more different. There might be other Peters but this one is a dragon. You define and show the difference by adding 'the dragon' information. Or you feel a need to state that information.